# Подсчитать сколько прошло времени через переменные

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

В базе данных есть дата и нужно вычислить сколько времени прошло от этой даты до текущего времени,сложность заключается в том ,что нужно работать с переменными.

```
$k234 =date("d/m/Y"); // получаем время на сервере 
$k235 = date("G.i.s");// получаем дату на сервере
```

Вот в таких ячейках лежат даты в бд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

// функции ниже достают значения в нужных ячейках $q50=времени $q60=дате

```
function printResul ($result_set) {
while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false) 
{
    global $q50;
    $q50=$row['data1']; 

}

}



$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT `data1` FROM  `имябазыданных` WHERE id=1"); // достаём время из бд 


printResul ($result_set); 











function printRes ($result_set) {
while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false) 
{
    global $q60;
    $q60=$row['data2']; 

}

}



$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT `data2` FROM  `имябазыданных` WHERE id=1"); // достаём дату из бд 


printRes ($result_set);
```

Comment: От даты до текущего времени это 00:00 17.06.2019 до допустим 17:03 18.06.2019?

Comment: ``4.43.24`` это что за дата?

Comment: 17.06.2019 4 43 24 вот дата и время в базе данных мы берём эту дату и подсчитываем сколько прошло времени от неё до настоящего времени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = '17.06.2019';
$time = '6.50.59';

$interval = (new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime($date . ' ' . $time));

var_dump($interval->format('%d.%m.%Y %H.%i.%s'));
```

Comment: string(15) "0.0.00 00.33.39"   это что?

Comment: Это сколько прошло времени =) 0 дней 0 месяцев 0 лет 0 часов 33 минуты 39 секунд

Comment: пытался $date присвоить $k234 но функции не работают,также а как тут вычислить разницу когда и нужно высчитывать разницу когда два числа таких 17.06.2019 18 .45.50    и  15.06.2019 18 .45.10

Comment: @Ivan912 `$interval = (new DateTime('17.06.2019 18 .45.50'))->diff(new DateTime('15.06.2019 18 .45.10'));`;

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере

```
$k234 = date("d/m/Y"); // получаем время на сервере 
$k235 = date("G.i.s"); // получаем дату на сервере
function printResul ($result_set) {
while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false) 
{
    global $q50;
    $q50=$row['data1']; 
    $d = new DateTime($q50);
    $d2 = new DateTime($k234.' '.$k235);
    $interval = $d->diff($d2);
    echo $interval ->getTimestamp(); // тут будет разница в секундах
}
}
```

Comment: ошибка 500 от базы данных

Comment: База не может выдавать ошибку 500. Эту ошибку выдает только сервер. Код выше будет частью вашего. нужно его встроить в ваше решение.

Answer (score 0):

Разица во времени -

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),concat(`data1`, ' ', `data2`)) as `difference`  FROM  `имябазыданных` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Либо секундах\минутах\днях и т.д. -

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, concat(`data1`, ' ', `data2`), NOW()) as `difference`  FROM  `имябазыданных` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Comment: выдаёт ошибку 500

Comment: Какой именно код выдает ошибку 500?